# Can't click the login button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, href

I have tried using `.click()`, `.submit()` and `driver.get()`, but nothing seems to work. The site is gosgc.com

The <div is:

```
<!-- -->
<div_ngcontent-c1=""class="user user--login">
<a_ngcontent-c1=""class="recover-username"href="/recover- user"routerlink="/recover-user" routerlinkactive="menu__item-- 
active">Forgot Username?</a>
<a_ngcontent-c1=""class="button">Login</a>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try one of the following:

```
# catching the element (login button) using xpath
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/sgc-web/div/general- layout/div/div/div[3]/a[2]").click()

# catching the element (login button) using CSS Selector
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > sgc-web > div > general-layout > div > div > div.user.user--login > a.button").click()

# catching the element (login button) using class name
driver.find_element_by_class_name("button").click()

# catching the element (login button) using link text
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Login").click()
```

Comment: Thanks!  The first one worked great.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome!